# missed files while building veins_inet

Tags: omnet++, veins, inet

I'm using `inet4 omnet5.5.1 veins5` I imported veins_inet in the workspace but it doesn't build successfully even though I added the paths to inet and veins src files in project properties I got the following error:

```
15:29:41 **** Incremental Build of configuration gcc-debug for project veins_inet ****
make MODE=debug all 
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/nai/omnetpp-5.5.1/myWorkspace/veins_inet/src'
Creating shared library: ../out/gcc-debug/src/libveins_inet_dbg.so
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lINET_dbg
Makefile:141: recipe for target '../out/gcc-debug/src/libveins_inet_dbg.so' failed
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/nai/omnetpp-5.5.1/myWorkspace/veins_inet/src'
Makefile:36: recipe for target 'all' failed
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lveins_dbg
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [../out/gcc-debug/src/libveins_inet_dbg.so] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
"make MODE=debug all" terminated with exit code 2. Build might be incomplete.

15:29:43 Build Failed. 6 errors, 0 warnings. (took 1s.693ms)
```

apparently some required files are missing

how to fix this please

Comment: thank you now veins_inet builds without errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be building this project in debug mode, but not building the other projects in debug mode.